# replace-regexp-in-string not replacing the entire match

Tags: regular-expressions, url

So, I have a function that sends a URL to bit.ly for shortening and returns the short URL, and a `(replace-regexp-in-string)`, which is supposed to grab the URL out of a string to passes it to that function.

Funny thing is -- both of these work fine on their own, but when I combine them, I end up with a mess.

```
(defun crshd/shorten-url (url)
  (let* ((bitly-url (format "https://api-ssl.bit.ly/v3/shorten?access_token=%s&format=%s&longUrl=%s"
                            crshd--bitly-api-key
                            "txt"
                            url))
         (response-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously bitly-url)))
    (with-current-buffer response-buffer
                (buffer-substring (+ url-http-end-of-headers 1) (- (point-max) 1)))))

(replace-regexp-in-string "http.?://[a-z0-9./?&%#-_=]+"
                          'crshd/shorten-url
                          "replace http://emacs.stackexchange.com in this string"
                          nil nil)
```

And I end up with `"replace http://emachttp://bit.ly/2a1zTGW.stackexchange.com in this string"`

At the same time, `(crshd/shorten-url "http://emacs.stackexchange.com")` returns `"http://bit.ly/2a1zTGW"`, as expected.

```
(defun crshd/foo-url (url)
  "foo")

(replace-regexp-in-string "http.?://[a-z0-9./?&%#-_=]+"
                          'crshd/foo-url
                          "replace http://emacs.stackexchange.com in this string"
                          nil nil)
```

Also returns `"replace foo in this string"`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it is because the function from url.el is modifying [the Match Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html) within replace-regexp-in-string, if so, you can use `save-match-data` to keep the Match Data unchaged after calling `crshd/shorten-url`.

Comment: Tangentially, did you mean to include the *range* `#-_` in your character alternative? I haven't checked what that would be, but it *looks* like a mistake.

Comment: @xuchunyang That was it. Should be an answer, so I can accept it :P

Answer (score 2):

Emacs search functions (such as `re-search-forward`, `replace-regexp-in-string` etc) store the search result as [the Match data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html). The later search overwrites the previous search's Match data by default. If you have to do another search within one search, you need to save & restore the Match data before/after the inner search, Emacs provides [`save-match-data`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Match-Data.html#Saving-Match-Data) for this purpose.

```
(replace-regexp-in-string some-regexp
                          (lambda (_match)
                            (save-match-data

                              do-another-search

                              ))
                          some-string)
```